# Get every sub-element of an R object

Tags: r

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to even ask that.

This results in a dataset

```
criteria <- lapply(graphs, function(graph){
  get_criteria(graph, n_immunize)})
```

which looks like that:

```
$lattice
$lattice$highest_pagerank
  [1] 999 998 997 ...
$lattice$eigenvector_centrality
  [1] 508 509 507 ...
$lattice$betweenness_centrality
  [1] 572 573 571 ...
$lattice$closeness_centrality
  [1] 500 501 502 ...
$lattice$highest_degree
  [1]  82  83  84  ...

$erdos_renyi
$erdos_renyi$highest_pagerank
  [1] 828 242 821 ...
$erdos_renyi$eigenvector_centrality
  [1] 828 821 242 ...
$erdos_renyi$betweenness_centrality
  [1] 828 242 821 ...
$erdos_renyi$closeness_centrality
  [1] 828 242 821 ...
$erdos_renyi$highest_degree
  [1] 828 242 821 ...
```

where for each network there are lists of integers.

My problem is that I would like to select all of the $highest_pagerank lists across all networks and then all $eigenvector_centrality lists across all networks and so on.

Something to the extent of:

```
myData[,1] and myData[,2]
```

I hope it is clear what I would like to achieve.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `lapply(criteria,"[[","highest_pagerank")` should do it (or use `sapply()` to get the results simplified to a vector)

Comment: Oh that's awesome, does the trick perfectly, thank you! I've been trying to get the data out of it properly for over an hour now and I couldn't phrase the problem to search for a solution. Thanks again :)